# Firebase Auth not getting initialized in spring boot

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am using firebase admin sdk in my spring boot app. (API app)

When I run locally in intelliJ its working fine. But when deployed in tomcat its giving me NPE.

In Springboot application

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(InfanoApplication.class, args);

    try {
        ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

        File file = new File(classloader.getResource("firebase2.json").getFile());
        logger.info("FILE PATH : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl(FB_BASE_URL)
                .build();

        firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        logger.info("FIREBASE NAME : "+firebaseApp.getName());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In API code

```
userRecord = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(InfanoApplication.firebaseApp).getUserByPhoneNumber(mobile);
```

ERROR:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.firebase.ImplFirebaseTrampolines.getService(ImplFirebaseTrampolines.java:62)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(FirebaseAuth.java:101)
```

Can someone help in fixing this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is null here that the NPE is complaining about?

Comment: @DougStevenson FirebaseAuth.getInstance is returning null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't create an instance of Firebase like this in the main method. Probably your service account is not being found in the proper classpath. I would create a [Spring Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) which creates a Firebase app on application startup. I have kept my service account in the **root of *resources folder***.

```
@Configuration
public class FirebaseConfig {

    //TODO: In your case maybe something else
    @Value(value = "classpath:serviceAccount.json")
    private Resource serviceAccountResource;

    @Bean
    public FirebaseApp createFireBaseApp() throws IOException {
        InputStream serviceAccount = serviceAccountResource.getInputStream();

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("<db-url>")
                .setStorageBucket("<storage-url>")
                .build();

        //Add loggers
        System.out.println("Firebase config initialized");

        return FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    }

    
    @Bean
    @DependsOn(value = "createFireBaseApp")
    public StorageClient createFirebaseStorage() {
        return StorageClient.getInstance();
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn(value = "createFireBaseApp")
    public FirebaseAuth createFirebaseAuth() {
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn(value = "createFireBaseApp")
    public FirebaseDatabase createFirebaseDatabase() {
        return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn(value = "createFireBaseApp")
    public FirebaseMessaging createFirebaseMessaging() {
        return FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Now if I want to use Firebase Auth in any of my service classes I would just do the following:

```
@Service
class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    //TODO: Probably should have return type
    public void findUser(String mobile) {
        firebaseAuth.getUserByPhoneNumber(mobile);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just followed your steps and I am getting following error. java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'long com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.exhaust(java.io.InputStream)'

Comment: Sorry that issue was due to firebase admin sdk version change from 6.13.0 to 7.0.0. That issue gone once reverted the version.

Comment: Is it safe to put the service account file that contains secrets in the `resources` folder so the public cannot access it?

Comment: @BlueBoy, its not safe. For a single dev hobby project good enough, but if you have multiple devs with different roles then you should not put it in prod. Probably use a secret manager or something like [Vault](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault)

Comment: @Vault I mean is it a safe from the public when the app is live? Like, can external users on the internet list or view the items in the resources folder somehow? Or is it secure from that the way WEB-INF is?